# React hooks calling with ternary operations

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks, usefetch

const allUsers = useFetch(fetchUsersApi, [id]); const usersWithoutAccess = useFetch(fetchUsersApi, [id, queryParams]); const { data: permission } = useFetch(fetchPermissionApi, [id]); const users = permission.value ? allUsers : usersWithoutAccess;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot call hooks conditionally<sup>1</sup>. Every time you render you must call exactly the same hooks in exactly the same order. If you don't, react can't tell which hook corresponds to which, so it can result in things like the wrong state being returned from a `useState` hook.

Fixing this typically is done one of two ways:

1. Modify the hook so you can pass in a parameter to disable it. Eg, `null` could indicate that it should not fetch.
2. Split the code into a separate component, and only render that component when you want to fetch.

If you'd like details on how to do these, please edit your question to include the code for `useFetch`

<sup>1) [Except for the upcoming use hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/use)</sup>

Comment: Okay, thanks Nicholas! In my component, I display users. There's this new change where I have to fetch some permissions, and if permission is true, then I show all users. If not, I should fetch users who don't have permissions and display them.

Ideally, I did something like this:

Comment: `const allUsers = useFetch(fetchUsersApi, [id]);
const usersWithoutAccess = useFetch(fetchUsersApi, [id, queryParams]);
const { data: permission } = useFetch(fetchPermissionApi, [id]);
const users = permission.value ? allUsers : usersWithoutAccess;`

Comment: But in this case, if permission is false, I don't have to display usersWithoutAccess, yet I have fetched the data. I wanted to avoid that, so I thought of doing it conditionally. Then, I remembered I should not use a custom hook in a ternary.

Comment: useFetch is used in the code at the top to fetch data, Im not sure I can modify it :(